# Preventing Load event on every ShowDialog

Tags: c#, winforms, showdialog

The ParentForm contains only one button "Open Second Form" onclick event it calls

```
private void Parent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChildForm _chld = new ChildForm();
        _chld.ShowDialog();
    }





private void ChildForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "This is Child Form";
    }

    private void Ok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
    }
```

Child Form Contains Textbox ,Ok Buttons and  ChildForm_Load,Child_Click event of OK button.

On clicking the "Open Second Form" button it opens Child form with the content "This is Child form " in the textbox.

Here my scenario is like this,

When I first click on the OpenSecondForm it opens ChildForm with content "This is Child form " in text box.I Changed the text box to "This is Parent Form" and then OK.

But when i again click on "Open Second Form" button the text in the text box is showing old text "This is Child form " but not changed text "This is Parent Form". The value is not persisting in the text box.

I think Load event is firing for every showdialog(). Is there any way to prevent the load event for second time.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new form every time, so the default values are being displayed.  I'm guessing you want just one ChildForm to ever display, so move the variable to the parent form's scope:

```
ChildForm _chld = new ChildForm();

private void Parent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  _chld.ShowDialog();
}
```

Make sure to dispose of that ChildForm, too, when the parent closes:

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e) {
  _chld.Dispose();
}
```

The Load event will still fire, so just remove your line or move it to the constructor:

```
public ChildForm() {
  this.InitializeComponent();
  this.textBox1.Text = "This is Child Form";
}
```